# Why I can use method 'each' in List interface in Groovy?

Tags: java, groovy

I am a beginner for Groovy. I feel confused for the `List` interface. According the type, it is an instance of `java.util.ArrayList`. And there is no method `each` in Java JDK for ArrayList.

Why I can type below code:

```
list = [1, 2, 3]
list.each { println "- ${it}" }

println list.class
```

Comment: Because [Groovy is not Java](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/documentation/working-with-collections.html).

Comment: As @LutzHorn said Groovy is not Java - so learning it on Java is bad idea, also tag Java is not good here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Groovy adds methods to existing classes to support its coding style.

For example [these are all the methods added to the `List`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/List.html) interface, including [the `each` method](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/List.html#each(groovy.lang.Closure)).

A rough overview over the additional features added this way can be found in the [Groovy Development Kit overview page](http://groovy-lang.org/groovy-dev-kit.html).